# Como identificar e corrigir erro 00302 no Oracle?

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, oracle11g

Como posso corrigir um erro desta natureza (ERRO 00302) e como saber a linha em que está o erro no oracle SQL Developer?

```
Error(16,6): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(16,52): PLS-00302: component 'NOME_PESSOA' must be declared
Error(17,6): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(17,52): PLS-00302: component 'ID_ENDERECO' must be declared 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_GERA_ENDERECO_AFTER AFTER INSERT ON pessoa

DECLARE
   -- cria o tipo para variável que armazena o conteúdo do package
   TYPE tbPessoaPackage IS TABLE OF pessoa%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   tbPessoa   tbPessoaPackage;
   x           BINARY_INTEGER; --indice

 BEGIN
   -- atribui ao índice o primeiro valor do package
   x := pkg_pessoa.vPessoa.FIRST;
   -- limpa a var criada
   tbPessoa.DELETE;

   -- adiciona todos os registros do package na variável criada
   WHILE x IS NOT NULL LOOP
     tbPessoa(x).id_pessoa := pkg_pessoa.vPessoa(x).id_pessoa;
     tbPessoa(x).nome_pessoa := pkg_pessoa.vPessoa.nome_pessoa;
     tbPessoa(x).id_endereco := pkg_pessoa.vPessoa.id_endereco;
     x := pkg_pessoa.vPessoa.NEXT(x); -- incrementa o valor do índice
   END LOOP;

   pkg_pessoa.vPessoa.DELETE; -- limpa o package
   x := tbPessoa.FIRST; -- atribui ao índice o primeiro valor

   -- loop para percorrer todos os registros do package
   WHILE x IS NOT NULL LOOP
     -- insert na tabela endereco, com o nome da rua sendo Rua + nome da pessoa (ex: Rua do Felisberto)
     BEGIN
       INSERT INTO endereco (id_endereco,lograddouro) values (seq_endereco.nextval, 'Rua do ' || tbPessoa(x).nome_pessoa);
     EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001
                                ,'Não foi possível inserir os dados na tabela ENDERECO. Trigger: T_GERA_ENDERECO_AFTER ' || SQLERRM);
     END;
     -- update na tabela Pessoa, para setar o valor do id_endereco da Pessoa com o valor do id do endereço gerado no insert acima
     BEGIN
       UPDATE pessoa p SET p.id_endereco = seq_endereco.currval
        WHERE p.id_pessoa = tbPessoa(x).id_pessoa;
     EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002
                                ,'Não foi possível atualizar os dados na tabela PESSOA. Trigger: 
                                T_GERA_ENDERECO_AFTER ' || SQLERRM);
     END;
     -- atualiza valor do indice para o proximo registro
     x := tbPessoa.NEXT(x);
   END LOOP;

 END;
 /
```

Comment: Olá @Orlando seja bem vindo, é interessante dá uma lida no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site pra entender melhor como funcionam as regras por aqui.

Comment: Olá @Orlando, você poderia postar a parte do código relevante do código em que esses erros estão acontecendo? (Veja [MVCE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: As tuas tabelas possuem apenas 5
sendo duas para colunas Endereco e tres para Pessoal

Comment: Percebi que criou duas contas diferentes, recomendo que entre em contato através da página http://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact e solicite mescla das contas

Answer (score 3):

Um erro [`PLS-00302`](http://pls-00302.ora-code.com/) no Oracle PL/SQL significa que algum componente utilizado no código do *statement* não foi declarado.

Os motivos mais comuns para que isso aconteça são:

- Esquecer de declarar variáveis
- Declarar variáveis com o mesmo nome de algum artefato (e.g., você tem um `SCHEMA` e um objeto qualquer com o mesmo nome)
- *Typos* (declaração e uso com nomes diferentes).

Os erros apontam respectivamente o número da linha e o número da coluna em que o erro ocorreu. Por exemplo `(16,6)` significa décima sexta linha, sexta coluna. Veja que a linha não necessariamente é contada a partir do começo da janela e sim do bloco executado.